# What is the purpose of [.] in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, posix

I found `[.]` in a regular expression on [manpage of notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/manpages/notmuch-search-terms-7/):

```
notmuch search 'from:"/bob@.*[.]example[.]com/"'
```

It seemed to be useless because brackets are for list but have only one character, but finally I learned it matches a literal dot.

Then, why they use it rather than `\.`?  Are there any advantages on this expression?

Comment: TIL, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is in contexts where the backslash requires its own escaping, e.g. string literals.

Comment: @Bergi that would be my guess too

Comment: `\.` and `[.]` is the same. However, `[.]` is preferable when you do not know escaping rules (how many backslashes to use to escape the dot in some weird environment). `\.` is correct and preferable *regex string*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought that this is to avoid double escaping but on further consideration I think this is because a dot in a character set (`[]`) is treated differently than normal. It makes sense that in a character set a dot only matches a literal dot, the whole point is to match a specific set of characters so having a *wildcard* in the set doesn't make sense.

So `[.,;:]` may be used to match punctuation marks.

Once you take that into account it's obvious that `[.]` just matches dot.

Whether to use `\.` or `[.]` is left as an aesthetic decision.

Comment: It's not just aesthetic, it's as @WiktorStribiżew commented on the question.